# Classes for preventing damage

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, optimization, class

I'm new to dungeons & dragons and I am looking to play a support role within the campaign so I want to know which class can mitigate the most amount of damage for my party members.

I'm thinking of using shielding spells to either mitigate the damage taken or to block enemies from reaching the players while also using a combination of buffs and healing spells to increase their chances of avoiding attacks and to increase players hit points to absorb successful attacks.

Currently I'm looking at the protection domain cleric, an abjuration wizard, an alchemist artificer or possibly a theurgy wizard for a mix of the first two.

Comment: Recommendations are very opinion based which this site tends to shut down. You can instead rephrase it to "which class can mitigate the most damage for party members" so there is an objective way to answer.

Comment: I'd recommend that you take a look at this meta post, you might find a better place to ask this question: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go

Comment: Currently, this question is written too broadly. When you state 'mitigating damage' are you referring exclusively to hit point damage? Or are you also concerned about boosting saves to ensure more successes? When you refer to mitigating damage, are you referring to effects the confer resistance, or do you include things that boost AC? There are many ways to play a combat support character, so it's difficult to assess what kind of support character you're seeking without additional, clarifying information.

Comment: @András The protection domain is [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_Cleric.pdf) material

Comment: This looks like a solid [type 2 charop](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/23064), with a little workshopping. You've already articulated your requirements of Maximum Damage Mitigation ([See 2.2.3 of Dr. Ballsun-Stanton's paper](https://www.academia.edu/5690704/Constrained_Optimization_in_Dungeons_and_Dragons_A_Theory_of_Requirements_Generation_for_Effective_Character_Creation)). To further improve, you could take a look at the non-closed type 2 charop questions in the meta link above, and follow how they asked.

Answer (score 1):

## Lore Bards are the best at damage prevention

Bards can use Bardic Inspiration to help with saving throws, possibly negating lots of damage.

A 3rd level Lore Bard can use Cutting Words to turn a hit into a miss. This also consumes Bardic Inspiration points.

At 5th level the Bardic Inspiration points return on short rests too.

At 6th level they can learn two spells from any spell list, so if you find a nice wizard or cleric spell that fits the theme, you can have it. (Up to 3rd level)